# Tailwind CSS not applying display: flex on sm:flex

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I have a div with the following classes

```
 <div class="hidden sm:visible sm:flex">
  ....
</div>
```

where the sm:visible is being applied as

```
@media (min-width: 640px) .sm\:visible {  visibility: visible; }
```

but the class `display: flex` is not being applied

as a side note the intellisense  is not showing it either

I'm using `vue-cli-plugin-tailwind`

Comment: Add the contents of your `tailwind.config.js` in a code sample as well.

Answer (score 0):

So as @JHeth pointed out I should check my tailwind config so my issue was in my tailwind.config.js
Where it was as follows

```
 variants: {
…
       display: ['group-hover'],
     },
```

Instead in the ‘extend’ property so instead of extending I was overriding

So I changed it to

```
 variants: {
    extend: {
      …
      display: ['group-hover'],
 },
}
```